# Container from ASP.NET Core Docker Image says 'No .NET SDKs were found'

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile, containers

My .NET Core project includes a Framework reference of Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App for use of a 3rd party library Data Matrix reader. I can build and run the project without issues. I  want to containerize the application using Docker.

I've created a Dockerfile as below:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as build-env

WORKDIR /src

# Docker caching benfit: Copy only the csproj files and then run dotnet restore
COPY src/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy rest of of source files into image
COPY src .

# Build the project
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /publish

# Specify image to run in application & define at runtime stage
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 as runtime

# Specify the working directory for this stage.
WORKDIR /publish

# copy the /publish directory from the build-env stage into the runtime image.
COPY --from=build-env /publish .

# Expose port 80 to incoming requests.
EXPOSE 80

# Tell Docker what command we want to run when our image is executed inside a container. We do this using the ENTRYPOINT command.
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "dm-code-reader.dll"]
```

I have built the image using:

```
docker build -t net-dm-reader -f Dockerfile .
```

However when I attempt to run the container (using Docker Desktop on Windows) I receive the following output.

```
2023-05-22 17:10:38 You must install or update .NET to run this application.
2023-05-22 17:10:38 
2023-05-22 17:10:38 App: /publish/dm-code-reader.dll
2023-05-22 17:10:38 Architecture: x64
2023-05-22 17:10:38 Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '7.0.0' (x64)
2023-05-22 17:10:38 .NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
2023-05-22 17:10:38 
2023-05-22 17:10:38 No frameworks were found.
2023-05-22 17:10:38 
2023-05-22 17:10:38 Learn about framework resolution:
2023-05-22 17:10:38 https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
2023-05-22 17:10:38 
2023-05-22 17:10:38 To install missing framework, download:
2023-05-22 17:10:38 https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

I am aware the solution is included in the lines:

```
2023-05-22 17:10:38 To install missing framework, download:
2023-05-22 17:10:38 https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=7.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

However, I've tried and failed to install the missing framework and ended up faffing with different base images and just getting myself confused.

Surely there must be a straightforward way to instruct the download and install of this framework to solve the error when I run the container?

Comment: Is your application a desktop application?